# Removing loaded pyd files

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ctypes

I'm writing an updater for an application. I need to remove the old files as they're running. This works fine until I hit dll files that I'm using. For various reasons I have to bundle the `_ssl` compiled library with my distribution.

I'm firstly freeing the library, which for whatever reason requires two calls to actually remove the handle (I'm assuming there is refcounting going on somewhere). After this, I try and remove the file. This results in Python dying with a `0xC0000005` which is apparently a very broad exit code.

```
import ssl
import ctypes
import _ctypes

print "Unloading SSL Module"
ssl_filename = ssl._ssl.__file__
dll = ctypes.CDLL(ssl_filename)
if ssl_filename.endswith("pyd"):
    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(dll._handle)
    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(dll._handle)
else:
    _ctypes.dlclose(dll._handle)
    _ctypes.dlclose(dll._handle)
print "Deleting current version..."
os.remove(ssl_filename)
print "Success"
```

Upon execution I get the following:

```
Unloading SSL Module

__builtin__ C:\path\to\_ssl.pyd 0 Deleting current version...

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

What I'm expecting is for the code to remove the file and continue as normal.

Comment: There were reference counts for a reason.  You forced the DLL to be unloaded, but there was still code being called in that DLL, probably at process exit.  0xC0000005 is an access violation because the code/data being accessed is gone.

Comment: So if I remove all references to it, that'll work?

Comment: Assuming there isn't something in a .pyd implementation that always gets called on exit, probably.  Lacking a documented way to unload a .pyd, you can only try.

Comment: Trying to do this is a bad idea. CPython isn't designed for unloading extension modules. On Windows, mapped image/data files such as DLLs can be renamed while loaded, in case it helps to relocate in-use files to another directory while updating.

Comment: I decided to create a new instance of my process that hooks in before all the DLLs are imported as an alternate solution to this. The old process downloads and saves the new version, restarts, unpacks everything and continues the load process